# Dividing arrays keeping their keys

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am doing an aplication (Discord bot with nodejs) which can display strings. The problem is that the embed I am using can only display strings shorter than `1024`. I have developen a code that divides the whole string into an array, but the problem is when It divides the code in the middle of a Collection key.

How can I divide the code when all the Collection has ended and not exceding 1024 length?

Here is the code I developed:

```js
let string = "Lorem" // U can generate a string here http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/random-string-generator/
let number = (Math.floor(string.length/1024));
let strings = new Array();
for(let a = 0; a < number+1; a++) {
  let aux = "";       
  aux = string.substring(a*1024,(a+1)*1024);
  strings.push(aux);
}
```

An example of my error is the following:

```js
// First string
[...]
'Incompl
// Second string
eteString' => ...
```

Here is an image of the actual "error":

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what is your error. I ran your code and it seems fine. What do you mean by " when It divides the code in the middle of a Collection key."? 
Can you provide an example of input that cause your code to fail?

Comment: @alcyon just edited the quesiton

Comment: Sorry, still not clear for me. Can you provide a codepen (https://codepen.io/pen/) example which fails? This way one can really reproduce your issue and investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to split long strings. This is no-loop-only-map variant.

```js
const random = (from, to) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from) + from)
let veryLongString = Array(random(2048, 10240)).fill(0).map(pr => String.fromCharCode(random(40, 80))).join('');

const chunkSize = 1024;
const numberOfChunks = Math.floor(veryLongString.length / 1024);
let chunks = Array(numberOfChunks).fill(0).map((pr, index) => {

  const from = index * chunkSize;
  return [
    from,
    from + chunkSize > veryLongString.length ? veryLongString.length : from + (chunkSize - 1)
  ]
})
.map(([from, to]) => veryLongString.slice(from, to))

console.log(veryLongString.length, chunks.length, chunks)
```